# Firebase project created by terraform not visible

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm new to terraform so not sure if I did something wrong. Just started using firebase as well... I was basically creating a new "environment" for a new firebase project using terraform. I was successfully able to create a dev environment. I mistakenly thought I could use the the same code base and just change the env to update project name/id but the `terraform plan` showed that it would replace my resources so I duplicated the directory, deleted all the generated terraform files, ran an `init`, `plan` and what I thought was a successful `terraform apply`

Terraform confirmed 12 resources added and generated the `tfstate` file. I have the firebase config and everything however I can't find the project in console or using `firebase projects:list`. It's as if it's not part of my org - I used the same org_id for dev. Pretty sure it's there because when I try to recreate manually I get an error saying the project id exists. Need some advice on how to debug this issue as I'm just not familiar enough with GCP.

Comment: Do you see your project ID there: https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Unfortunately not. That's the first place I looked. Then the regular GCP console, then the firebase cli, then the gcloud cli

Comment: Sometimes you can create projects outside of your org if the terraform structure is incorrect. Take a look at the google admin console - https://admin.google.com and see if it appears in there with no org connection. If you are not an org superuser you will not be able to access this. If this is the case, ask a supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

So the project eventually showed up in firebase, but it took more than 24 hours. I have no clue what would cause that but I can't imagine that would be normal or acceptable. At this point I'm assuming it has something to do with terraform since Firebase support for it is technically in beta. Not sure if I can submit a bug without a support plan but I'll look into.